# In R, How can I run a Multiple linear model estimation under robust standard error in HC3, so I can carry out a Chow test?

Tags: r, testing

I am trying to make a wage model, with data from Uruguay, under the following form:

```
mod <- lm(logsalxhora ~ 
      exper + mujer + menoresde14años_hogar + 
      sq_menoresde14años_hogar + informal + casado + separado + 
      noblanco + q_trabajo,
      data = ECH.2019)
```

But due to heteroskedasticity, I need to run the estimation under robust standard error, with HC3.

Which I achieved doing the following:

```
mod <- lm(logsalxhora ~ 
     exper + mujer + menoresde14años_hogar + 
     sq_menoresde14años_hogar +  informal + casado + separado+ 
     noblanco + q_trabajo,
           data = ECH.2019)
robust_se <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(mod, type = "HC3")))
```

But in order to do a Chow test, I think I need to create an object which contains this model under that specific form of estimation, but I don't know how.

I have a code with which I can run a chow test:

```
devianceSR <- deviance(mod1) + deviance(mod2)
n <- length(modrestricto$fitted.values)
k=mod2$rank -1
chow <- ((deviance(mod) - devianceSR)/devianceSR)*((n-2*(k+1))/(k+1))
p.valorF = pf(chow, k+1, n-2*(k+1), lower.tail = F,)
```

But in order to do so, I need the model as an object, not as a value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `dput(df)` would be helpful for users who want to help to reproduce and troubleshoot your issues